# what is the impact of disabling Tracker on Sitecore OOTB Marketing Analytics reports

Tags: experience-analytics

Is it possible to see the sitecore OOTB **Marketers** **Analytics** **reports** like the Page View visit after disabling Tracker only (Xdb.Tracking.Enabled = "false")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The tracker is responsible for tracking a contact’s activity on your website and submitting that data to xConnect at the end of the session..The tracker records a contact’s activities in session..* (**Refer :** https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/web-tracking.html)

If you disable `Tracker` in Sitecore, it will not record any of the contact's activities happening in a user's session.

You can get more insights on your question by referring to the below official Sitecore documentation on the "Effects of enabling/disabling the xDB or Tracking" table.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/enable-disable-the-xdb-and-the-tracker.html#UUID-6da95f68-d53e-7990-464d-35c826d11b2c_section-5c77c3117d8af-idm45463820988752

As you can see in the above link, on the other hand, if xDB is enabled, your past tracked user actvity data captured by the Tracker before disabling it, if any, will still appear in the Experience Analytics report as the xDB Reporting server role will still be able to read the past recorded data from the xDB Reporting database.

Comment: Thanks @paulson. One doubt is in Experience Analytics, there are 4 OOTB Reports (Audience,Acquisition,Behavior and Conversions), i would like to know whether all these reports data are showing based on user activities.
If so then tracker is disabled, non of these reports will show up right.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about whether all reports will stop showing data.. in the 2nd link, it says we can use goals, events etc.., in CD and that IP Gelocation is not available. Can you try disabling it once and check?

Comment: After disabling Tracking, no new entries were showing on the reports.Once I enabled the tracking back, it started showing new entries on those reports.

Comment: Nice.. Pls mark my above as answer if it answered your question and/or upvote if it helped you. Thanks!